# Ruby on Rails: Simply Can Not Render Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I want to be able to show users who have liked a user's post. I am going to provide a simple amount of information so this issue won't get overwhelming.

I have three classes involved:  User, Share and Opinion.  Their models are set up likewise:

```
class User
  has_many :opinions, foreign_key: "fan_id", dependent: :destroy
end

class Share
  has_many :opinions, foreign_key: "like_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, through: :opinions
  has_many :agreeables, foreign_key: "fan_id", class_name: "Opinion", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fans, through: :agreeables
end

class Opinion
  belongs_to :fan, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :like, class_name: "Share"
end
```

In other words:  `like_id = share.id` & `fan_id = user.id`

Then in my controller:

```
SharesController
  def show
    @share = Share.find(params[:id])
    @shares = @share.fans.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

I click the link to `share_path`, it renders the page but with nothing on it.  When I look at my SQL logs, **I notice the problem:**

It is not inner joining opinions correctly to have the rendered share (`like_id`) match up with the users who liked the share (`fan_ids`).

Let's say the `share.id` was 11 and the `current_user.id` is 5.  It's query consists primarily of inner joining opinions to have the `like_id` **AND** `fan_id = 11`.

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem or an alternate method that is more practical?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

For any future readers, the solution was as followed:

```
class User
  has_many :fans, foreign_key: "fan_id", class_name: "Opinion", dependent: :destroy
end

class Share
  has_many :opinions, foreign_key: "like_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, through: :opinions
  has_many :fans, through: :opinions
end
```

And the `SharesController` and Opinion model was left unchanged.

Comment: I don't really get the purpose of all your association in your `Share` class and also you're referencing the `MicroPost` class but you're not showing the code of this class. Could you maybe explain in plain english what are the relations between your models ?

Comment: There's something strange with this line: `has_many :agreeables, foreign_key: "fan_id", class_name: "Opinion", dependent: :destroy`. This line will make it so that if you do `share.agreeables` it will look for an Opinion where `fan_id == share.id`. But you said that fan_id should be a user id.

Comment: pjam, I am sorry I fixed the incorrect data. Basically my goal is to make it where when you click a link on a User's post (Share) it will show who "liked" the post. Hense the has_many likes. It is already a working method, I just want to be able to show which users have liked that share. Sorry for the confusion.

Jesper, maybe this is the issue.  I am actually not looking for share.agreeables but share.fans (which I suppose would yeild the same results?  Would I need to exclude the fan line all together from this model?  If so, should it be included into the User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all users who liked a `Share`, the following code should be enough :

```
class User
  has_many :opinions, foreign_key: "fan_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shares, through: :opinions
end

class Share
  has_many :opinions, foreign_key: "like_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fans, through: :opinions # I'm not sure, but you might need to add class_name option here
end

class Opinion
  belongs_to :fan, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :like, class_name: "Share"
end
```

In your controller, 
`@shares = @share.fans.paginate(page: params[:page])` will return the list of users(fans)

EDIT : As you're not using conventional names (fan instead of User and like instead of Share), you might need to add more options like inverse_of and class_name, but I'm not really sure about that

Comment: Thanks!  This looks promising but there is only one problem.  I have already defined has_many :shares in my User model and my share table has user_id.  Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you're asking here, but you can write a new migration that would remove the useless user_id column for instance.

Comment: Ok I will try this.  And I am assuming the fan_id column in the Opinions table would be suffice?  Thanks I will try this asap!

Comment: Yes, the fan_id should be enough. And by the way, I don't know if I'm right, but I usually try to rely on rails convention for naming. In your code, that would be naming columns in `opinions` table `user_id` and `share_id` and then you can always alias methods to have the names you want such as `like` and `fans`

Comment: I looked at my code while I was attempting to apply these suggested methods and realized I must not have explained something correctly because I believe you misunderstood.  When a user "likes" a share they are inserted in the opinion table as fan_id and the "liked share" is inserted as "like_id"  Therefor I can not create a new migration and replace user_id with fan_id. @shares.fans would render ALL users in the table.  I just want to render "fans who liked" (users who liked a share")  Does this make sense?  I will work on it, but if you come with something let me know!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got it to work with your help, thank you!  I modified the original post to show.  Thanks!

Comment: But I do not understand.. the only thing I did was replace has_many :agreeables with has_many :fans... but they were both linked to the Opinion model.  So was it that.. or was it the change to the User model that corrected this error?